# "war on" or "war against" and "war for"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. we have waged a war **against** smog.
> 2. we have waged a war **on** smog.

If I want to figuratively convey the message we have started to tackle air pollution, smog in particular, which preposition should I choose?

Another question: if the war is fought to ensure we can always see blue skies, can I say we have staged a war for blue skies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check on Google Books Ngram Viewer, you will see that the expressions **war on** and **war against** are just about equally popular.

In my experience, **war on** is used typically for popular campaigns such as **war on waste**, **war on plastic** and **war on drugs**. In each of these **war** is being used as a metaphor for a campaign linked to ecology, pollution or health concerns.

**War against** is used mainly for actual wars in which one nation, tribe or group fights against another.

Sometimes the distinction is blurred. For example, one can choose whether a campaign to eradicate mosquitoes is a **war on** or a **war against** the pests.

As far as smog is concerned, you can wage a war on the causes but hardly on smog itself (except as a popular catch-phrase) and certainly not against it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_as_metaphor

Comment: Well explained! Oh I have another question: if the war are fought to get blue skies, can I say we fight a war for blue skies?

Comment: Yes, it's both grammatical and idiomatic, using **war** to mean a campaign.

Comment: Declaring a "war on X" when you really need a "war" against the causes of X is a long tradition going back at least to the War on Poverty. A "war on smog" seems to me to fit that pattern.